# How to dynamically change a text from URL input?

Tags: javascript, text, dynamic

I want something like that..

https://pl.sports-streams-online.best/?st=nbastream.tv&plcm=db&q=Raptors+vs+Lakers

See that URL part q=Raptors+vs+Lakers, If i input any text on this section it will automatically change on website body. I want to know how i can do this. I will input a text in URL and it will display on website body.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse `window.location` and put that into a div on your page. I can't show you in a code snippet because the snippets use an iframe but if your html has `<div id='uText'></div>` then you can use javascript (after the page has loaded) to set the value of that div with results of the query param. lets say your url ends in `?st=nbastream.tv&plcm=db&q=Raptors+vs+Lakers`, then you want the value for parameter `'q'`:

```js
function getQueryStringParam(param) {
  var url = window.location.toString();
  url.match(/\?(.+)$/);
  var params = RegExp.$1;
  params = params.split("&");
  var queryStringList = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var tmp = params[i].split("=");
    queryStringList[tmp[0]] = unescape(tmp[1]);
  }
  return decodeURIComponent(queryStringList[param]);
}
let qParam = getQueryStringParam('q').split('+').join(' ');
const div = document.getElementById('uText');
div.innerHTML = qParam;
```

Check out the codepen [here](https://codepen.io/ApoloPena/pen/jOqbZEd?st=nbastream.tv&plcm=db&q=Raptors%20vs%20Lakers).

Comment: Thanks apena. It worked!!!! If i want to add another parma name 'img" how to total code will be?

Comment: The url would have something like `&img=someimagename.jpg` appended to it and the javascript would get that data something like this: `let imgParam = getQueryStringParam('img').split('+').join(' ');` you can leave out the `.split().join()` part if you know the `img` param value will not contain spaces.